# I am compiling a node.js project with typescript but I am not sure how to run individual scripts

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a node.js project that I am compiling with typescript, it just occured to me, that I have a scripts directory for running various non-server tasks, such as a seed file. I can no longer call these files directly because they are now typescript, how do I run them individually? Or what am I supposed to do with them?

For info, I have a directory `scripts`:

```
| `~scripts/                
|   |-masterList.csv        
|   |-masterList.origin.csv 
|   `-seed.ts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ts-node` package. It will compile TypeScript files at runtime and execute them as regular JS.

1. `npm i -g ts-node`
2. `ts-node scripts/seed.ts`

Comment: This seems to work well. I suppose that there is no way around it running the parser every time I run the script.